# onClose not working in datetimepicker to set a defaultdate after the datepopup is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My JSP page has a Date field which displays a timestamp , and the date value can be selected from the datepopup , We have used datetimepicker for the datepopup and to select the date.

The date field is a column in the table and we have used the datatables to display the data.

After the total page load , when we click on the date popup to select the date select it the selected date is getting displayed and its working fine but when the date popup is closed with out selecting the date by clicking anywhere on the screen  the loaded value in the date field is replaced with the date 1899-12-31.

For this I am going with the following approach, I am trying to get the date value for the row which I selected to modify the date and assign it to a variable, and when I close the date popup with out selecting the date, I should set the defaultDate with the value stored in the variable.

But unfortuately "onClose" is not working in datetimepicker, Can any one please help me in achieving this.

Please find my code below:
DataTable code to show the date fields :

```
{
            "mData" : "dateAvailable",
            "mRender" : function(data, type, full) {
                <c:if test="${User.permission eq 'All'}">
                return '<div class="input-group form-group date dateTime"><input type="text"  readonly=true id="dateAvailable" name="dateAvailable" value="' + data + '" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control pull-right"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar pull-right"></i></div></div>';
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${User.permission eq 'ReadOnly'}">
                return data;
                </c:if>
            },
            "bSearchable" : true,
            "bSortable" : true
        }
```

datetimepicker code :

```
 $("#dataTable").on('init.dt processing.dt', function() {
        $('.dateTime').datetimepicker({ 
            format : 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ss',
            startDate: new Date(),
            minView: 2,
            autoclose : true,
            //defaultViewDate:$(this).find('#dateAvailable').val(),
            onClose:function($this){
                defaultViewDate:$(this).find('#dateAvailable').val()
            }
        });
    });
```

Control is not going into onClose function , not sure whether onClose works in datetimepicker, Please help me on this.

Comment: Try listening for the `hide` event. That should work.

Comment: you haven't specified which datetimepicker you are using, but if it relies on moment.js I would double check you are providing the correct `format`